# How to avoid a user to list a directory other than his home directory in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, centos, centos-7

I hope this could be possible.

I created a linux user, called `newuser`, whose root directory is a directory containing a web site application (this is a developer I hired to develop the site). That document root directory is, for example, `/home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite`

```
drwxrws--- 4 mainuser nobody 4096 Jul  3 19:01 newwebsite
```

By seeing Apache configuration, I saw that user and group it runs on is called `nobody`, so, I added the new user to the `nobody` group. That way, that user can read, upload and change files in that folder. On the other hand, Apache can read the files in order to show the web site in a web browser.

Well... when that user logs in, he falls in the document root directory for that site, but he can do a `cd ..`  and navigate and browse content of other directories inside `/home` and below.

How can I avoid that? It is not that simple as removing read permission since this user is in the same group as Apache. If I change read permission, Apache will be restricted to execute other web sites I have in other folders below `/home` directory.

Is it possible to accomplish what I need?

Operating system is: `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite` is the home directory for user `newuser`, and he should be able to write to that directory, why is that directory owned by user `mainuser`? Do both these users (`mainuser` and `newuser`) need to write to that directory at the same time?

If no, remove `newuser` from `nobody` group and change the owner of that directory (recursively, if anything already exists inside that directory) from `mainuser` to `newuser`: `chown -R newuser /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite`. You should also probably remove the `ws` permissions for group (unless the web application needs also to write something to this directory and not only read, then leave `w` in place). So the fixed permissions should be:

```
drwxr-x--- 4 newuser  nobody 4096 Jul  3 19:01 newwebsite
```

Ensure that `newuser` has no permissions to any other directories inside `/home` (of course, you need `x` permission for "other" on all the directories above `newwebsite` in order to be able to access that directory by `newuser` at all - but with only `x` he won't be able to see the contents).

This way Apache will be able to read the directory and `newuser` will be able to modify it, only `mainuser` will not have access. After the work on new website is finished, you can change the ownership of the directory and its contents back to `mainuser`.

If you need both `mainuser` and `newuser` to be able to access the directory at the same time, do the same as in above solution, but instead of changing the ownership of the directory by `chown` command, keep the ownership with `mainuser` and **add an ACL** for `newuser` enabling him to modify the directory:

```
setfacl -R -m u:newuser:rwX /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite
```

This gives additional permission for user `newuser` to read and modify the directory and its contents, besides the normal "owner, group, other" permission. When you're done and you want to remove the additional permission, use the command:

```
setfacl -R -b /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite
```

Comment: `mainuser` is the user that has full privileges over `home/mainuser` folder and below. This is the cPanel user. With that cPanel user I can have several submains web sites. For instance, `home/mainuser` has a folder called `public_html` where all websites created under that cPanel account resides. When I create a new subdomain, it is created at the same level as the `public_hml` folder, in this case, it was `home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl`. In this case, cPanel does some actions automatically, for example, create the directory and add the host to Apache configuration.

Comment: I used `setfacl -R -m u:newuser:rwX /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite`  and after running that command, nothing was shown, assuming command execution was successful. Then, I logged that `newuser` in and this error was shown: `-bash: /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite/.bash_profile: Permission denied` and the user is placed at `/` directory. What's wrong? I cannot even do a `cd /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite`.

Comment: @jstuardo I never believe such automation tools like cPanel. It is best to completely understand what each configuration operation does and do everything manually :). As for the error you are experiencing, what does `getfacl /home/mainuser/otherdomain.cl/customers/newwebsite` show? Something must be definitely messed up with permissions. Also show `ls -ld` and `ls -la` of the directory, `getfacl` on the `.bash_profile` file and all other diagnostic that could possibly help.

Comment: Please see this screenshot showing all the commands: https://prnt.sc/WJy4XvITlsoO

Comment: Hello... I discovered that Apache is affecting the permissions some way. Using `root` user I created a directory under `/home/mainuser`. I executed the command `setfacl` but using that directory. Finally, I logged in using the `newuser` and I could `cd` to it and even could create a file. When I `ls` that new file I saw that the user and group was assigned to `newuser`. Since I suppose Apache is not allowing to access that directory, is there a way to check and solve that? Or maybe, creating a directory manually and set Apache document root to that directory? I am not sure if it will work,

Comment: @jstuardo I mentioned that you need `x` permission for "other" on **all the directories above** `newwebsite` to be able to access it by `newuser`. I see on your output that this permission is not present on the direct parent of the directory (`..`) - maybe on upper directories too. If this is fixed, `newuser` should be able to access that directory, because permissions look OK.
As for Apache, it's a different problem. You must check `DocumentRoot` as well as various `<Directory>` sections in Apache config. Consult Apache documentation. Not knowing your Apache config, I can't say more.

Comment: Finally I got it work. I created the user in his default home directory. There I created a folder for the website. Since the subdomain was created using cPanel under mainuser (to make it easier also to install Let's Encrypt for SSL access) I edited httpd.conf file accordingly, changing the user for the website (to be able to execute PHP files) and the document root. After I set the default UMASK for the user, I have system how I needed so that the hired developer will be able to access only his folder and below. Thanks for your time.